# Press return and remain current cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way of remaining in the current cell after pressing enter/return in a cell? Excel has this as a preference and my end user is asking if it's possible.

I've found to go left, right, up and down after editing the current cell, but nothing or remaining in the current cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the left arrow and the right arrow together (at the same time).

Comment: AFAIK this is not in the [official doc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110), but works!.

Answer (score 0):

Late contribution after finding this question multiple times unresolved&locked on Google Docs Editors Help since 2010.

Came up with this Apps Script and it worked for me. There is a half-second delay to snap back to the edited cell though

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  sheet.setCurrentCell(range.offset(0, 0));
}
```

Breakdown:

`function onEdit(e)`
When a cell is edited

`var range = e.range; var sheet = range.getSheet()`
Defining range and current sheet for [setCurrentCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setcurrentcellcell)

`sheet.setCurrentCell` select this cell

`(range.offset(0,0))` moving it by 0 (from the time when it was edited).

So this script technically doesn't move the selection at all, it rather undoes the movement of selection by Google Doc's UI.